# How to bundle product in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I tried to develop a Shopify application and I needed to bundle some products and sell those together with the special discount values.

There are some apps like product-bundle but I need bundling product in my app.

I tried to create one product similar to them and after the purchase completed I delete it but I think it's not a good solution because this product will be shown to shop and other customers can purchase that while I want to offer this product to a certain customer only.

In another way, I tried to use Shopify discount but can't satisfy my need or maybe I can't find true ways.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which you can handle this.

1) **Create a product itself:**
Create a single product indicating a combination of your desired multiple products and combination of your price.
When the customer adds all the related products, detect it from cart webhook and update the cart of the customer by removing such products and adding the single product(i.e combination of all products).

2) **Create a discount code:** Create a discount code with your desired discount amount for each combo. Detect the products in the cart by cart webhook, if combo products found automatically apply the coupon to the cart.